# OpenCV - why Optical Flow does not work with dequeue<Mat>?

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I am trying to use Optical Flow on some videos. But it doesn't work at all when I don't resize the video.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback) I have set the parameters as:

```c
calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, current, flow, 0.5, 1, 10, 2, 5, 1.1, 0);
```

In case of videos that are scaled-down or up it works fine:

[image]
[image]

But in case of keeping the original size of the videos it does not work at all:

[image]
[image]

I have tried changing the parameters of the function:

```c
calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, current, flow, 0.5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1.1, 0);
//or
calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, current, flow, 0.5, 1, 50, 2, 5, 1.2, 0);
//or
calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, current, flow, 0.5, 1, 100, 20, 7, 1.2, 0);
...
```

But none of them make any difference. The result for original size videos is still no flow.

The [Lukas Kanade algorithm](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga473e4b886d0bcc6b65831eb88ed93323) has the exact same problem:

[image]
[image]

When I scale down the `720 x 480` or other high-resolution videos to half-size (`360 x 240`), Optical Flow algorithms still work well. But they don't work at all for videos without scaling (original size), no matter how I set the parameters.

How can I make Optical Flow work for videos without resizing the video?

Comment: Did you tried calcOpticalFlowPyrLK? I suggest you to check the documentation of OpenCV 4.2.0: https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga5d10ebbd59fe09c5f650289ec0ece5af

Comment: Can you make the working video frames resize(320,240) before the process? Because I tried in those sizes and worked fine.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk you are right. I scaled them to half size and still works. It seems that if the video's original size is big it works and otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: @Ali I tried `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`. But it has the same problem. Works well for higher resolution videos, but not at all for smaller videos!

Comment: It is ınteresting then...

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk funny thing. When I scale the videos with size `320 x 240` to half-size (`160 x 120`) or double-size (`640 x 480`) the Optical Flow works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60609562/6129428),
the problem was with the `current` and `prev` pointing to the same frame.

It was fixed by using `frame.clone()` instead of `frame` in the queue of frames.

```c
deque<Mat> frames;
...
frames.push_back(frame.clone());
...
current = frame;
prev = frames[frames.size() - 5];
...
calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray, current, flow, 0.5, 1, 10, 2, 5, 1.1, 0);
```