# OpenCV - How to push back Mat in a queue?

Tags: c++, opencv, resize, mat, deque

I am trying to put the frames of a video in a deque. This code does not work. Because the back and front of the queue are both the same as the current frame.

```c
deque<Mat> frameSeq;
int main() {
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture video("path to video");
    int key = 0;
    while (key != 'q') {
        video >> frame;

        frameSeq.push_back(frame);

        imshow("front", frameSeq.front());
        imshow("back", frameSeq.back());

        key = cvWaitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I resize the frame:

```c
deque<Mat> frameSeq;
int main() {
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture video("path to video");
    int key = 0;
    while (key != 'q') {
        video >> frame;

        cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(), 1.0 / 2, 1.0 / 2);
        frameSeq.push_back(frame);

        imshow("front", frameSeq.front());
        imshow("back", frameSeq.back());

        key = cvWaitKey(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works well. Now `frameSeq.back()` is the current frame and `frameSeq.front()` is the initial frame.

How can I make the queue work without having to resize the frame?

Comment: Given that in both of those examples you provided you push a single frame into the queue, it doesn't really matter what you do with the frame before -- the front and back will always be the same. Please, provide [mcve] that **actually demonstrates the problem** you mention.

Comment: @DanMašek I fixed that part.

Comment: You don't really need a `resize` specifically, the important part is a side effect of performing the resize -- since the new image is of a different size, the underlying buffer in `frame` gets reallocated and it's no longer shared with anything else. A simple deep copy would do as well (`frameSeq.push_back(frame.clone());`).

Comment: This is because `Mat` works similarly to a smart pointer. For performance reasons, `VideoCapture` (or potentially just the `>>` operator) reuses the same buffer for all the frames it returns. Normally it's not an issue, but in your case, you explicitly have to make copies.

Comment: @DanMašek thanks. That solved the problem. So `resize` is irrelevant. It just makes the pointer not shared.

Comment: Exactly, it was just a coincidence. Using a `Mat` with incorrect size/type as output causes a new, independent, array to be allocated. | One other potential approach might be, instead of the `clone()` to put `Mat frame;` inside the scope of the `while` loop. If that works, you avoid one copy of the whole buffer per iteration. (This would be the case if the reuse is due to the higher-scoped `frame` and `>>` just copying into it once it's the right size... and then you just populate the queue with shallow (shared) copies. -- which as I think of it more seems to fit better).